# Numpy log slow for numbers close to 1?

Tags: python, numpy, runtime

Look at the following piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

print('close', timeit.Timer(lambda: np.log(0.99999999999999978)).timeit())
print('not close', timeit.Timer(lambda: np.log(0.99)).timeit()))
```

The output is:

```
close 4.462684076999722
not close 0.6319260000018403
```

How come such big (orders of magnitude) difference in running time? Am I missing something?

EDIT:

More preceisly we see the slowdown for values as small as:
`1 - np.finfo(np.float).eps`
but not for values
`1 - np.finfo(np.float).eps * 10`.

My machine `Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)` with `numpy 1.11.1`.

This has been so far reproduced on 3 other machines from my side (2 Python 3.4 Anaconda installations, 1 Python 2.7 default Ubuntu installation).

Some other users could also reproduce it, while others could not. See comments.

EDIT 2:

Possibly only reproducible on Linux systems. So far, not reproducible on Windows systems.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Python 2.7.9, numpy 1.11.1. Both ~0.62 secs. Out of interest, what happens if you switch the order of execution?

Comment: FYI: If you are taking logs of numbers very close to 1, you might get more accurate results if you can modify your code to use `np.log1p` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html).

Comment: @roganjosh Just tried it and it is invariant to the order of executions. Can you try with the following two inputs `1 - np.finfo(np.float).eps` and `1 - np.finfo(np.float).eps * 10` to the log function?

Comment: @roganjosh: I can reproduce a similar difference both with Python 2.7 and Python 3.4. The ``close`` condition takes roughly five times longer than the ``not close`` condition.

Comment: @Schmuddi hmmm, this is unusual, I _definitely_ don't see anything like that on my system. For OP: Both again are coming out around the same time, with `1 - np.finfo(np.float).eps` ~1.4-1.6 sec and `1 - np.finfo(np.float).eps * 10` ~1.5-1.7 sec.

Comment: @Schmuddi Curious what is your Python installation? I have anaconda.

Comment: @Aleksandar: I'm also using an Anaconda installation. Hm...

Comment: @Schmuddi and OP: What's also interesting is that I'm running in Enthought Canopy to get those numbers. If I run the script in terminal, it consistently takes ~0.3-0.4 sec longer

Comment: Confirmed longer on 2 separate machines. One with python 3.4 Anaconda installation, and the second with python 2.7 default Ubuntu installation.

Comment: I think it might be worth unaccepting the answer for now and just giving it an upvote? That way you're more likely to get some traffic on this and perhaps someone can unpick it. I would also consider editing to include my observations (unable to replicate) + the fact you can repeat on two PCs (the comments section is quite long now to find this info out). Clearly there's something more complicated going on here.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've toyed around with a few other numbers. Up to ``0.99999999999999972``, I see the same performance as with ``0.99``. Starting with ``0.99999999999999973``, the time required to finish jumps up to the same timing as for ``0.99999999999999978`` (from the original example). Performance stays at this up to about ``0.99999999999999983``. Starting with ``0.99999999999999984``, the calculation is as fast again as with ``0.99``. Apparently there is a relatively narrow range where performance drops.

Comment: Even more puzzling. I'll try to produce a plot of time vs input number when I get back to my machine.

Comment: @Schmuddi and OP: We're getting closer! I am mainly on Windows 7 - cannot reproduce. Ported code over to Ubuntu - I get almost exactly the same as you guys.

Comment: @roganjosh Very interesting. I will try on my Windows machine as well and report back.

Comment: Spot on. My primary system runs Linux Mint (x64), and this is where I can reproduce @Alexsandar's results. Yet, I can't reproduce the performance difference on a Windows 10 system (32 bit, I think).

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, most chipsets evaluate `log` using a Taylor series coupled with a table of specific pre-computed values.

With the Taylor series, a number closer to 1 is slower to *converge* than a number further away from 1. That could go some way to explaining the difference in execution time observed here.

`0.99` may also be closer to one of the tabulated values, which would also help.

**Or your observations may not even be statistically significant.**

Comment: Interesting observation. If I run it with a number for `1-np.finfo(np.float).eps`, then I observe it, for a very slightly higher value of `1-np.finfo(np.float).eps * 10` it is no longer observed. I noticed it since I have an iterative algoritham, that pushes values towards 1, but in my calculation I was clipping it to `1-eps` instead. And when you have a huge matrix of such values, the slowdown in noticeable.

Comment: Your unaccepting this answer will not hurt my feelings. I think really that your observation is anomalous. Can you check `exp` as a control?

Comment: Only happens with `np.log`. I think it is significant since if I have the following inputs `a = np.ones((1000, 1000)) * (1 - np.finfo(np.float).eps)`
and `b = np.ones((1000, 1000)) * (1 - np.finfo(np.float).eps) * 10`, the difference is `38.169339494997985` vs. `0.16117668000151752`. That seems significant to me.

Comment: Thanks for unaccepting. I think the final answer is yet to emerge. (If you're able to reproduce in C then you could ask this on the C tag which is where many chipset experts lurk).

Comment: See also this paper. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=09A07E99C5E5669D4503C7903F80E2A7?doi=10.1.1.24.5177&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: We appear to have narrowed it down to a difference between Windows and Linux. On Windows, the problem cannot be reproduced (so far) but it's very obvious on Linux

Comment: I still think that removing `numpy` from this might help. Can you ask on the C tag? It's with some dismay that I have to report that I don't currently work with Linux.

Comment: You would have to tag OP in your comment to change it, I can't do anything with this question :) I'm just following it out of curiosity because I don't know anywhere near enough about why they would be fundamentally different.

Comment: @Bathsheba You mean to run a similar experiment in pure c?

Comment: @Bathsheba as to your previous comment, swapping `numpy` for `math` has no effect on Linux

Comment: @Bathsheba @roganjosh I am also seeing same slowdown using `math` as well.